# A better verb than build up?

Tags: word-request

> The government decided to build up the curriculum to place more
> emphasis on ethics.

Is there a better verb a verb that's more appropriate? I would like it to be a phrasal verb if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Beef up** is an option:

> to make something stronger or more effective, esp. by adding more support — [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/beef-up-something)

For example:

> [What Your State Is Doing To Beef Up Civics Education](https://www.npr.org/sections/ed/2018/07/21/624267576/what-your-state-is-doing-to-beef-up-civics-education)

It's colorful albeit slightly informal.

Comment: Yes, it exists but I find it rather vulgar....

Comment: @Lambie There's nothing vulgar about it: it comes from the same expression used literally to refer to building up muscles. It would be a little extreme for even a vegan to object to the expression (even considering the other meaning of beef).

Comment: Laurel, I upvoted you, I used three periods in my comment.  I **personally do not like the sound** of it, it makes me think of beefy guys in sweaty gyms boxing or so forth. And I am not vegan.